# Can I bring over stored procedures to a new database all at once?

Tags: sql, database, stored-procedures, implementation

I create a large amount of stored procedures based on data we receive from clients to implement into our CRM. We receive a final "cut" of data right before go-live and create a new database for it. Is there a way to bring over all of the stored procedures and view created to that new database without manually, 1 by 1, "script stored procedure as > create to > new query editor window" and running them against the new database?

Comment: You need a migration tool because doing this manually is going to be trouble. Someone will miss something, especially if you have to do this more than once.

Comment: A version control tool (github?) might make this process significantly easier for you.

Comment: Depends on whether or not you want to test them.

Comment: Easiest way I have found without purchasing another component: Use Visual Studio. Make SSDT project for your database & sprocs. Do a Schema Compare. You can make 2 Schema Compares if you want to first import your test environment into SSDT project, and then secondarily to go from SSDT to production. This will save you from manually adding them all to the project. Just don't mess up the source & targets...